# Query data of the first document of my sub collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

I need to get the data of the first document (only) of my sub collection.

I have tried this first solution :

```
void _getOwner(accommodation) async {

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('Accommodation')
        .doc(accommodation.id)
        .collection('Owner')
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((value){
          print(value.data());
        });
  }
```

But I have this error message :

> The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
>
> - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'
>   ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.15.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'data'.
>   print(value.data());

Then I have tried this solution :

```
  void _getOwner(accommodation) async {

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('Accommodation')
        .doc(accommodation.id)
        .collection('Owner')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["LastName"]);
          })
    });
  }
```

It works, but I need the LastName of my first Owner document, not "forEach"... what should I do ?

Comment: Please show the actual problem, not the code you *think* is right - console.log's, error messages, etc.  There are many ways the above could generate an error. 

=> does the document exist?
=> does the field exist in the document?
=> is the field name actually 'email'?
=> ```DocumentSnapshot.data``` is an object, not an array, although the ```[ ]``` syntax can often work.

Comment: I have updated my post to give you more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your section:

```
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["LastName"]);
          })
    });
```

querysnapshot.docs is an array of QueryDocumentSnapshots (NOT the final documents), and can be addressed as an array.  I caution that the concept of "first" is a tricky one in Firestore - you should define your own order, and use an `.orderBy()` in your code; otherwise it will be in order of documentID, which I *hope*, for performance reasons, is a pseudo-random code.  Assuming it is actually the "first" in whatever order you have described, you could do:

```
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
        print(querySnapshot.docs[0].data.LastName);
    });
```

As a general rule, using the dot(.) notation is better for fixed, known field names; the array notation `doc[variable]` is best left for, well, when you need to use a variable to reference the fieldname.